# Errors installing linux-firmware

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

While I try running:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/44,8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4 096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 219082 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.157.14_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.157.14) over (1.157.13) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.157.14_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/firmware/ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin' to '/lib/firmware/ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-041300-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-40-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.157.14_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong is clearly stated in the error message: `dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean # clean cache
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f # resume apt-get with fix broken flag
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # pull new dependencies
```

Comment: but `The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
`

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. It will pull new dependencies.

Comment: I had a bunch of old libraries and images sitting around, and I am not sure why was it the issue, but `apt-get autoremove` solved my problem